# Is it possible to write image to disk in parallel ? (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, io

I am trying to facilitate writing series of images acquired from ipcam streaming, so I've used a producer consumer pattern, where producer put image into a queue, while consumer read image out of queue. Is it possible to improve the saving to disk performance by creating multiple thread to handle write to disk ?

Because the mechanism how file are write to disk, would this approach be eventually have same performance as a single thread writer ?

Comment: To see any performance gain, you will need to write to multiple disks. The task is I/O bound and using threading doesn't increase the amount of I/O you can do per second. It is possible to see some benefit in threading if there's significant CPU time involved in saving the file (e.g. compression) but it's not usual.

Comment: So, if I were to write the file to a RAID for example, open multiple thread might be beneficial, but not if I am only write to a single disk ?

Comment: A RAID might not t help, because it's a single device as far as your program can tell. A single thread might be able to saturate it. If not, then additional threads can help. But usually you'd want each thread to write to a separate drive hooked up to a separate controller.